# official binance-api swift4 compile error

Tags: xcode, macos, swift4, binance

about this https://github.com/dpyro/BinanceApi.
I use XCode 10, macos 10.13/10.14 and swift 4.2. I did do what is written in the readme file, but I still got an error.
The log is a little bit long so I insert here a small portion.

```
"*** Fetching BinanceApi
*** Fetching Alamofire
*** Fetching CommonCrypto
*** Checking out CommonCrypto at "v1.1.0"
*** Checking out Alamofire at "4.8.0"
*** Checking out BinanceApi at "1.0.0"
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/21/3s7vv3qx2nj9z6870sdf9bp40000gp/T/carthage-xcodebuild.cWa4BS.log
*** Downloading CommonCrypto.framework binary at "Version 1.1.0"
*** Building scheme "Alamofire iOS" in Alamofire.xcworkspace
*** Building scheme "Alamofire macOS" in Alamofire.xcworkspace
*** Building scheme "Alamofire watchOS" in Alamofire.xcworkspace
*** Building scheme "Alamofire tvOS" in Alamofire.xcworkspace
*** Building scheme "BinanceApi" in BinanceApi.xcodeproj
Build Failed
    Task failed with exit code 65:
    /usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -project /Users/LA/Projecten/Binance/Libraries/BinanceApi-master/Carthage/Checkouts/BinanceApi/BinanceApi.xcodeproj -scheme BinanceApi -configuration Release -derivedDataPath /Users/rva/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/10.1_10B61/BinanceApi/1.0.0 ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CARTHAGE=YES archive -archivePath /var/folders/21/3s7vv3qx2nj9z6870sdf9bp40000gp/T/BinanceApi SKIP_INSTALL=YES GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS=NO CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE=NO STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT=NO (launched in /Users/LA/Projecten/Binance/Libraries/BinanceApi-master/Carthage/Checkouts/BinanceApi)
```

-

the error part in the log when it fails is this.

"

```
CompileSwift normal x86_64 (in target: BinanceApi)
    cd /Users/LA/Projecten/Binance/Libraries/BinanceApi-master/Carthage/Checkouts/BinanceApi
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c ...........0  swift                    0x0000000108bb459a PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 42
1  swift                    0x0000000108bb3d4e SignalHandler(int) + 302
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff5dac1b3d _sigtramp + 29
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x0000000000000005 _sigtramp + 2723407077
4  swift                    0x0000000105c22843 (anonymous namespace)::ObjCPrinter::visitBoundGenericType(swift::BoundGenericType*, llvm::Optional<swift::OptionalTypeKind>) + 179
5  swift                    0x0000000105c1eabb swift::TypeVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::ObjCPrinter, void, llvm::Optional<swift::OptionalTypeKind> >::visit(swift::Type, llvm::Optional<swift::OptionalTypeKind>) + 443
6  swift                    0x0000000105c1e9e6 swift::TypeVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::ObjCPrinter, void, llvm::Optional<swift::OptionalTypeKind> >::visit(swift::Type, llvm::Optional<swift::OptionalTypeKind>) + 230
7  swift                    0x0000000105c19425 (anonymous namespace)::ObjCPrinter::print(swift::Type, llvm::Optional<swift::OptionalTypeKind>, swift::Identifier, (anonymous namespace)::IsFunctionParam_t) + 629
8  swift                    0x0000000105c2063b (anonymous namespace)::ObjCPrinter::finishFunctionType(swift::FunctionType const*) + 347
9  swift                    0x0000000105c19535 (anonymous namespace)::ObjCPrinter::print(swift::Type, llvm::Optional<swift::OptionalTypeKind>, swift::Identifier, (anonymous namespace)::IsFunctionParam_t) + 901
10 swift                    0x0000000105c1d048 (anonymous namespace)::ObjCPrinter::printAbstractFunctionAsMethod(swift::AbstractFunctionDecl*, bool, bool) + 3336
11 swift                    0x0000000105c1aafd void (anonymous namespace)::ObjCPrinter::printMembers<false, swift::IteratorRange<swift::DeclIterator> >(swift::IteratorRange<swift::DeclIterator>&&) + 461
12 swift                    0x0000000105c17d5e swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::ObjCPrinter, void, void, void, void, void, void>::visit(swift::Decl*) + 6350
13 swift                    0x0000000104e4c326 printAsObjCIfNeeded(llvm::StringRef, swift::ModuleDecl*, llvm::StringRef, bool) + 4710
14 swift                    0x0000000104e43c92 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 39522
15 swift                    0x0000000104e36d35 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 7717
16 swift                    0x0000000104ddc965 main + 1349
17 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff5d8d808d start + 1
18 libdyld.dylib            0x000000000000004e start + 2725412802
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c .... 
1.  While generating Objective-C header
2.  While printing extension of _ObjCBinanceApi at /Users/LA/Projecten/Binance/Libraries/BinanceApi-master/Carthage/Checkouts/BinanceApi/BinanceApi/BinanceObjCApi.swift:170:14
3.  While printing type '_ObjCBinanceApi.ResponseHandler<[String : Date]>' (declared at [/Users/LA/Projecten/Binance/Libraries/BinanceApi-master/Carthage/Checkouts/BinanceApi/BinanceApi/BinanceObjCApi.swift:137:12 - line:137:79] RangeText="typealias ResponseHandler<U> = (_ result: U? , _ error: Error?) -> V")
4.  While printing type 'U?'
error: Segmentation fault: 11

<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
<unknown>:0: error: compile command failed due to signal 11 (use -v to see invocation)
"
```

I did remove the recurring file names for the sake of the text size.
The only thing that I get out of this is this line

```
BinanceObjCApi.swift:137:12 - line:137:79] RangeText="typealias ResponseHandler<U> = (_ result: U? , _ error: Error?) -> V")
```

But don't know how to fix this because I don't get a pre compiler error warning and I use Swift.

Being busy for 6 hours but whatever I do I cant find the solution. Please, any suggestions?

BTW, how can I avoid that it compiles for every apple device? I only need the macos version.

Comment: When the compiler crashes on you, you should report this as a bug to Apple at bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Ha, just clean up everything, restart the whole system, and did compile everything separate, again. And ...... it did compile. Only, if I use the lib I get a notification "Unable to load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides)" and in a test Project I get 'BinanceAllPricesRequest' initializer is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level" Does this mean that I have to correct an init in the library? Everything is already public.